# Need a date field to return blank in SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server and do NOT have write access to the DB. I can only extract.

I am left joining to the nph2 table to see if there are records. If there isn't a record, I just need the field to be blank. To illustrate what I am trying to do, one of the fields is 'Status' and this works fine:

```
case when lsf2.STARTDATE > lsf.STARTDATE and lsf2.STARTDATE is not NULL then 
lsf2.LEGALSTATUS else '' end as 'Status'
```

The other field is a date field and I can not make anything similar work. Such as:

```
case when lsf2.STARTDATE > lsf.STARTDATE and lsf2.STARTDATE is not NULL then 
nph2.STARTDATE else '' end as 'StartDate'
```

I keep getting '1900-01-01 00:00:00' or an error.

And I understand why I am getting that. I have tried several ways to convert etc., but nothing works.

Basically if my date case is not met because there is no record that meets it, I still need a row with other data in it, but need the date field to populate with nothing.  Any ideas would be great.

Comment: Can you post your full query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either settle for `NULL` in the results or cast the *entire expression* to a varchar type. You will not be able to put an empty string into a date column.

```
coalesce(cast(case when lsf2.STARTDATE > lsf.STARTDATE then nph2.STARTDATE else NULL end as varchar(20)),'') as 'StartDate'
```

Comment: Thank you!  You are a mad genius, that works!!  I don't understand coalesce so need to read up on that.  I do have a question, my results where there are dates are formatted like this:  'Feb 19 2016 12:00AM' Is there a way to format it to '2016-02-19' instead?  Thanks for the help!